# I'm trying to make separate graphs in an R loop, but every graph is using the same data (the last element in my list)

Tags: r, loops, graph

I'm sure this is simple, but I'm pretty stuck. Below is my code:

```
# Create graphs in list

# Create titles for plots
titlenames <- c(harps)

 for (i in length(harps)){ for(j in titlenames) {

counts <- table(Y[[i]][[5]], Y[[i]][[3]])
data_percentage <- apply(counts, 2, function(x){x*100/sum(x,na.rm=T)})

# Create pdf of score breakdown

# For Hotel Name Subtitle
hotelname <- hotel_report$`Hotel (Q15 1)`[hotel_report$`Harp Number`==j]

pdf(file = paste0(j, ".pdf"), paper = "USr", width=8, height=7)
par(mar = c(5.1, 7, 4.1, 2.1))
breakdown <- barplot(data_percentage, main = "Breakdown of Property Score Distribution", sub = hotelname, 
        col = coul, las = 1, cex.names = .6, horiz = TRUE, yaxs="i", xlab = "Percentage",
        cex.axis = .8, cex.lab = .8, cex.main = .8, cex.sub = .8)
dev.off()
 }}
```

I would like data_percentage to change based on the iteration of the loop (there are 391 dataframes in list Y) before it graphs, but all my graphs are using the final version of data_percentage from Y[[391]][[5]], Y[[391]][[3]].

Does anyone know how I need to alter my code so the first graph is using data_percentage based on Y[[1]][[5]], Y[[1]][[3]], the second graph Y[[2]][[5]], Y[[2]][[3]], etc?

Thank you!

Comment: try `for (i in 1:length(harps)){ for(j in titlenames) ...`

Comment: @LocoGris, oops originally I misread and deleted a bracket, this does fix my problem! Thanks so much!